# Make Random Numbers Tend / Average to a Specific Value

Tags: c++, random, numbers

How can I for example generate a list of random numbers between 0 and 1, but have them avarage at 0.8?

I have written this little script in C++ that'll tell you what numbers got output. This question is not really C++ related though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argCount, char** argVector) {
    std::cout << "Generating Randoms" << std::endl;

    float avarage = 0.F;
    srand(rand() + (int) time(NULL));
    float ceiling = 0;
    float bottom = 1;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        float random = (float) (rand() % 101) / 100;
        if(random > ceiling)
            ceiling = random;
        else if(random < bottom)
            bottom = random;
        avarage += random;
    }
    std::cout << "Avarage: " << avarage/1000000 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Ceiling: " << ceiling << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bottom: " << bottom << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Generating Randoms
Avarage: 0.499287
Ceiling: 1
Bottom: 0
```

I would like the ceiling and bottom to be still 0 and 1, but be able to change the average. The algorithm should preferably be efficient too.

Once again, I'm now posting C++ code, but any language will do.

Comment: Do you have a preferred distribution?  There are many choices if you want to set `mu`.  e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution.  or perhaps a uniform distribution, or beta, or...

Comment: Well, if the average is 0.5, like it's now, I would like all numbers to have as much chance to be picked as 0.5. If it's like 0.7, I'd like  numbers to have more chance as they get closer to 0.7, to make the average result in 0.7. So it's not really any f that wiki page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You want a uniform distribution with a mean of 0.5, but a non uniform distribution if the mean is to be different than 0.5?  You need to specify the 'chance' of a number being close to 0.7, in the normal distribution example this is basically the variance parameter.

Comment: The chance is a straight line at 1% chance. If you want 0.70 to be the average, turn the line a bit so 0.70 is still 1%, but the numbers in front of it will have less chance and the numbers in front of it more.

Comment: Can you draw what you mean?  Label the axis please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NolanPower had a great idea using powers, but the mechanism he recommended for choosing the power is off.  If the random numbers `U` are uniform(0,1) the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) says we can derive the expected value of any function `g(U)` as `Integral[g(U) from: 0 to: 1]`.  If our function `g(U)` is a polynomial, i.e., `U**c` for some constant `c`, evaluating the integral yields the general solution `1 / (c + 1)` as the expected value.  Setting this equal to the desired mean `m` and solving, we get that `c = (1 / m) - 1`.

To get an expected value of 0.8, `c = (1 / 0.8) - 1 = 0.25`, i.e., crank out `U**0.25`.  To get an expected value of 0.2, `c = (1 / 0.2) - 1 = 4`, i.e., generate values using `U**4`.

Comment: Thanks for making me feel smart before making me realize I'm not!

Comment: @NolanPower Hey, you're plenty smart.  The basic approach was very clever.  It's just that distributions are non-intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that generates a standard normal distribution, i.e. `mu` = 0, `sigma` = 1.

I used the [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller_transform).

All plots have `x axis = value` and `y axis = frequency`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argCount, char** argVector) {
    const double pi = 3.14159265359;
    const double nums = 1000000;
    double u, v, x;

    srand(rand() + (int) time(NULL));

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nums; i++){
        u = rand() / (((double)RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
        v = rand() / (((double)RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
        x = sqrt(-2*log(u)) * cos(2*pi*v);

        if (std::isfinite(x)){
            std::cout << x <<" ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: standardnorm]

```
>>> np.std(nums)
1.0004139708929858
>>> np.average(nums)
7.1785002756408726e-05
```

You can shift/scale `x` as necessary to obtain a `mu` and `sigma` of your choosing.

Here's an example that gives a uniform distribution with a given `mu`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argCount, char** argVector) {
    const double pi = 3.14159265359;
    const double nums = 1000000;
    double x,mu;

    srand(rand() + (int) time(NULL));
    mu = 3.0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nums; i++){
        x = rand() / (((double)RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
        x *= 2*mu;

        if (std::isfinite(x)){
            std::cout << x <<" ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: unif]

```
>>> np.average(nums)
3.0003091558133184
```

You can use the [documented](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) `rand() % range + min` to truncate.

Answer (score 1):

Raise your number to the .321928 power will make the average .8 and still range from 0-1.

Comment: How do I calculate that number?

Comment: Gives you a lot of inaccuracies though. (e.g. 0.3 as average when pointing for 0.2)

Comment: What power did you use when going for .2?  Should have been 2.32192

Comment: log(.2) / log(.5) = 2.32193

Comment: Managed to fix it by only converting it to a 0->1 value after powering it. 
double logger = log(70) / log(50);
float random = (float) pow((double) (rand() % 101), logger) / 100;