# how to generate random numbers with a specified mean

Tags: random

I have a question like, I should genearate 'k' random numbers lets say it is from 1 to 1000. But the generated numbers should have a mean value of 300. I used rand() function to generate random numbers. But I am stuck with the mean value. How can I do so that the numbers generated have a mean value.

Comment: What does this question have to do with [tag:unix]? What does your algorithm look like thus far and how can we help you to fix it?

Comment: Integers only, or is the range continuous?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795265/make-random-numbers-tend-average-to-a-specific-value and scale the results appropriately to your desired range.

Answer (score 1):

I'd generate k-1 random numbers, and then set the K number to be (mean*k-[sum of all the numbers you generated so far]).

Comment: This could easily violate the range requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the C standard does not guarantee that the random numbers are uniform (it doesn't specify any distribution, for that matter), so the only way to do it is to generate the 1000 numbers in advance, calculate the mean (M) and subtract `M-300` from every element